# Group By, Count and get Total by items inside list

Tags: c#, linq

I have an Account object like:

```
public class Account
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public List<Elegibilities> Elegibilities { get; set; }
}

public class Elegibilities
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Label { get; set; }
   public bool Value { get; set;}
}
```

My repository returns a List of Account. `List<Account>`

I want to group by and count by items in `Elegibilities` and the output would be like:

```
{
   Total: 30,
    [
       {
          Id : 1,
          Label: "Elegibility1",
          Count: 10
       },
       {
          Id : 2,
          Label: "Elegibility2",
          Count: 20
       }
    ]
}
```

I'm having issues because it's a list inside another list.

Is it possible to solve in a single LINQ query?

Comment: What is Id in the expected result? account Id ! or Elegibilities Id?

Comment: Elegibilities Id

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look's like you don't want any data related to the Accounts,

This gives you a simple flat list to work with.

```cs
var flatList = accounts.SelectMany(a => a.Elegibilities);
```

This could be another example if you needed to include accounts related data to the output.

```cs
var group = from a in accounts
            from el in a.Elegibilities
            group el by el.Id into elGroup
            select new
            {
                Id = elGroup.Key,
                Count = elGroup.Count(),
                Label = elGroup.First().Label
            };
```

In the end you can access your group totals.

```cs
var result = new { Totals = group.Count() , Elegibilities = group.ToList() };
```

Comment: Brilliant! Works perfect! In fact I don't need any item from Accounts so I removed the first "from" sentence.